# $n\mid \phi(a^{n}-1)$ for any $a>n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, congruences, totient-function

I saw the proof which goes as follows:

$a^{n} \equiv 1 \pmod{a^{n}-1} $, and $n$ is the smallest power of a such that this is true.

We also know that by Euler's Identity $a^{\phi(a^{n}-1)}\equiv 1\pmod {a^{n}-1}$

So we get $n\mid \phi(a^{n}-1)$.

---

Now I am unable to understand where is the fact that $a>n$ is playing role?

Comment: isnt it eulers theorem instead of identity?

Comment: It isn't playing a role at all - the statement is still true if $a<n$. Perhaps you mean to ask about the requirement that $a$ and $n$ are relatively prime (which **is** necessary)?

Comment: @ZevChonoles I'm missing why $(a,n)=1$ is necessary.

Comment: @ZevChonoles try with a=2 and n=3

Comment: @PhaniRaj $2^3-1=7$ and $3|\phi(7)=6$. Nothing wrong there.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Ah, I was thinking that it is a requirement to apply Euler's theorem, but of course in this case the modulus is $a^n-1$, and $a$ and $a^n-1$ are always relatively prime, so I was incorrect.

Comment: Only thing one should mention that  $a$ is an integer and $a>1$.

Answer (score 4):

It's not. Nothing in that proof requires $a>n$, and, indeed, the theorem is true for all $a>1,n\geq 1$.

For example, you gave $n=3,a=2$. But then $a^n-1=7$ and $3|\phi(a^n-1)=6$

Answer (score 0):

What we can say is $$ord_{(a^n-1)}a\mid gcd(n,\phi(a^{n}-1))$$

As $ord_{(a^n-1)}a=n, n\mid gcd(n,\phi(a^{n}-1))$

If $a=2,n=5, \phi(2^5-1)=31-1=30$ which is divisible by $5(=n)$.

If $a=2,n=7, \phi(2^7-1)=127-1=126$ which is divisible by $7(=n)$.

Comment: Except $a^n\equiv 1\bmod (a^n-1)$ and there can't be any $0<k<n$ such that $a^n-1\mid a^k-1$, so we do know that $\mathrm{ord}_{a^n-1}(a)=n$. Because $a$ is relatively prime to $a^n-1$, by Euler's theorem we have $a^{\phi(a^n-1)}\equiv 1\bmod (a^n-1)$, which implies that $n\mid \phi(a^n-1)$ because $\mathrm{ord}_{a^n-1}(a)=n$.