# Prove $n\mid \phi(2^n-1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, totient-function

If $2^p-1$ is a prime, (thus $p$ is a prime, too) then $p\mid 2^p-2=\phi(2^p-1).$

But I find $n\mid \phi(2^n-1)$ is always hold, no matter what $n$ is. Such as $4\mid \phi(2^4-1)=8.$

If we denote $a_n=\dfrac{\phi(2^n-1)}{n}$, then $a_n$ is [A011260](http://oeis.org/A011260), but how to prove it is always integer?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: :nice question $\color{green}{\large+1}$

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> Consider $U(2^n-1)$. Clearly $2\in U(2^n-1)$. It can also be shown
>   easily that the order of $2$ in the group $U(2^n-1)$ is $n$. By
>   Lagrange's theorem $|2|=n$  divides $|U(2^n-1)|=\phi(2^n-1)$.

**Remark:** Thank you for letting me know about this fact. It's interesting!

Comment: An interesting answer!

Comment: @Hecke Yes. I didnt expect to find a short proof at the beginning !

Comment: You proved $n\mid \phi(a^n-1).$

Comment: @Hecke I already realized this !!

Answer (score 15):

$(\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{(a^n-1)Z})^*$ is a group of order $\phi(a^n-1)$ and gcd$(a,a^n-1)=1\Rightarrow a\in (\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{(a^n-1)Z})^*$

We have  $a^n\equiv 1\mod (a^n-1)$ and $a^k-1<a^n-1$ when ever $k<n$ so there does not exist $k<n$ such that the above condition holds. So the order of $a$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{(a^n-1)Z})^*$ is $n$. And as the order of each element divides the order of the group so we have $n|\phi(a^n-1)$

Putting $a=2$ we have the required result asked in the question.

Comment: Thanks,this is more detailed.

Comment: @Abhra, this can be generalized to $n|\phi(a^n-1)$  for any integer $a$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I think i have already generalized it to all integers.

Comment: @AbhraAbirKundu, may be my comment & your edit were concurrent. Anyway, good job.

Answer (score 11):

**Hint:** Clearly $2$ has order $n$, modulo $2^n-1$.

> **Further Hint:** We know that $2^{ \phi(2^n -1)} \equiv 1 \pmod{2^n-1}$.

Comment: Yeah....

This was actually quite straightforward. Sorry.

Answer (score 9):

**Observation.** If $2^n-1\mid 2^k-1$ then $n \mid k$.

*Proof.* Let $2^n-1\mid 2^k-1$. Let $k=qn+r$ where $0\le r<n$. Then we get 
$$2^k-1=2^{qn+r}-1=2^{qn+r}-2^r+2^r-1=2^r(2^{qn}-1)+2^r-1.$$
Since $2^{qn}-1=(2^n-1)(2^{(q-1)n}+2^{(q-2)n}+\dots+2^n+1)$, we see that $2^n-1$ divides $2^{qn}-1$. Therefore $2^n-1$ also divides
$$2^r-1 = 2^k-1 - 2^r(2^{qn}-1).$$
But $2^n-1 \mid 2^r-1$ with $0\le r<n$ is only possible if $r=0$. So we get that $k=qn$ and $n\mid k$.

---

From [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_theorem) we have
$$2^{\varphi(2^n-1)}\equiv 1 \pmod{2^n-1},$$
i.e., $2^n-1 \mid 2^{\varphi(2^n-1)}-1$. (Notice that $\gcd(2,2^n-1)=1$, so Euler's theorem can be applied here.)

Using the above observation for $k=\varphi(2^n-1)$ we get
$$n\mid \varphi(2^n-1).$$

Note: The same argument would work to show that $n\mid \varphi(a^n-1)$ for any $a\ge2$. Some posts about this more general question:

- [$n\mid \phi(a^{n}-1)$ for any $a>n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269859/n-mid-phian-1-for-any-an)
- [$n$ divides $\phi(a^n -1)$ where $a, n$ are positive integer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398165/n-divides-phian-1-where-a-n-are-positive-integer)
- [Prove that $n$ divides $\phi(a^n -1)$ where $a, n$ are positive integer without using concepts of abstract algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594233/prove-that-n-divides-phian-1-where-a-n-are-positive-integer-without)

Comment: This is basically Calvin Lin's answer rewritten in a more elementary language. (His answer was originally posted [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/608794/suppose-that-n-1-prove-that-n-divides-%CF%86-2n-1), but the two posts [were merged](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/608794/revisions).)

Answer (score 3):

I will use [Lifting the Exponent Lemma(LTE).](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Resources/Papers/LTE.pdf)

Let $v_p(n)$ denote the highest exponent of $p$ in $n$.

Take some odd prime divisor of $n$, and call it $p$.
Let $j$ be the order of $2$ modulo $p$.

So, $v_p(2^n-1)=v_p(2^j-1)+v_p(n/j)>v_p(n)$ as $j\le p-1$.

All the rest is easy. Indeed, let's pose $n=2^jm$ where $m$ is odd.

Then $\varphi\left(2^{2^jm}-1\right)=\varphi(2^m-1)\varphi(2^m+1)\varphi(2^{2m}+1)\cdots\varphi\left(2^{2^{j-1}}m+1\right)$. At least $2^j$ terms in the right side are even.

Comment: You are assuming $j|n$ but if $n=7$, $p=7$ then $j=3$...