# Suppose that n > 1. Prove that n divides $ φ (2^n - 1) $ .

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, totient-function

Suppose that n > 1. Prove that n divides $ φ(2^n - 1) $ .

Hint: Show that 2 has order n mod $ 2^n - 1 $